# Remove particular value from pandas dataframe which do not fit the sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe  which has time series column:
They follow a particular sequence except few junk values
I am looking to remove rows based on time column. As it is seen 1276.400 is not fitting the sequence and hence it is require to remove the entire rows.
I know how to remove pandas rows based on conditions but unable to come up with solution for this particular problem

```
.......
    583.19732
    583.397583
    583.5975952
    1276.400146
    583.7976074
    583.9976196
    584.1975708
    584.396123
    584.597834
    ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to choose some logic to determine what you consider an outlier. We can't help with this. You know your data best.

One option is to use [`pd.Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html). This gives you some flexibility to define the margin of error. On the other hand, it does *not* look specifically at adjacent values.

```
df_filtered = df[df['col'] < df['col'].quantile(0.90)]

print(df_filtered)

          col
0  583.197320
1  583.397583
2  583.597595
4  583.797607
5  583.997620
6  584.197571
7  584.396123
8  584.597834
```

Comment: @ jpp  Can u eleborate what is quantile and how 0.90 is selected.. It is new to me

Comment: Quantile is a mathematical term representing a probability distribution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile. 90% is a user input; as I said, *you* need to specify what's right for your data.

Comment: Ok and how 0.90 is choosen

Comment: @Poka, It's a **user input**. I plucked a number out of thin air to provide an output. **You** should **choose** a number to suit your data and needs.